# ArcGIS REST Services Directory - this type of layer cannot be turned on or off

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server, layers, map-service

I'm new to arcgis.

I've downloaded the layer with all the geological information from here

[map server](http://mapas.igme.es/gis/rest/services/Cartografia_Geologica/IGME_Geologico_1M/MapServer)

I only need to see some of the information of this map, but I get "this type of layer cannot be turned on or off".

How can I go around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The service is what is called "cached". This means it is pre-rendered as is and served as a bunch of image tiles. Here is a link to more on cached services. http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/what-is-map-caching-.htm
Maybe poke around the services directory for one that doesn't have the property Single Fused Map Cache: true.